# Why do I get this error when I run manage.py validate?

Tags: django

Why do I get this error when I run `manage.py validate`?:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 218,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 347,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\validate.p
y", line 9, in handle_noargs
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 245,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 146, in
 get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 61, in
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 78, in
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\projects\mysite\..\mysite\books\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Publisher(models.Model):
  File "C:\projects\mysite\..\mysite\books\models.py", line 6, in Publisher
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=30)
  File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 542, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maxlength'
```

Comment: @Balu: please take a moment to learn how to use Stack Overflow.  The title of this question is unhelpful, the code needs to be formatted so that it is readable, and you've included unimportant history in your console session.  We don't need to know that you mistyped "dir" as "div".

Comment: I've reformatted the code, again (2nd time now). Please use the code button (or simply indent your code with 4 spaces) in the future :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a newer version of Django now. Since 1.0 (or actually, somewhere in 0.97) Django switched to `max_length` instead of `maxlength`. So either upgrade your code or install Django 0.96 for it to work again.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be 100% sure, because you haven't included the code in mysite/books/models.py, but it would appear that the 'max_length' keyword argument to a CharField in the Publisher class has been misspelled 'maxlength'.

See here for the correct values:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield